# My bluetooth connected with nokia but not connected with android

Tags: android, bluetooth, project

I am making bluetooth app in android studio everything works fine having problem when i connect bluetooth with my android mobile it is not connecting but when i connect it with my brother c2-02 it's now connected why?????

My connecting thread is given below

```
     private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
         private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
         private BluetoothAdapter mybluetoothAdapter;
         private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
         private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
         public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
             BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
             mmDevice = device;
             try {
                 tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
             } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             mmSocket = tmp;
         }


         public void run() {
             //mybluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
             try {
                 mmSocket.connect();
             } catch (IOException connectException) {
                 try {
                     mmSocket.close();
                 } catch (IOException closeException) { closeException.printStackTrace(); }
                 return;
             }

         }
         public void cancel() {
             try {
                 mmSocket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();  }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. What do you mean by "when I connect bluetooth with my android mobile. . ." What is bluetooth? Your computer? Another phone? Is your phone running the code given? You are using an authenticated socket. Have you paired your android mobile and the other bluetooth device apriori?

Comment: another phone in which my application

Comment: yeah but not connected with android mobile amazing thing is that it is connected with c2-02 which is not android why??????

Comment: Ok. Have you paired the android mobile to the phone running the application? The createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() method requires an authenticated socket. Which means the two devices need to have a pre-existing security relationship.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned above tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not correctly using createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(). *Before* you use that method, you need to pair your mobile device with the device with which you want to communicate. You should read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID).

You could try using createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() to verify that you don't have some other issue. But I suspect since it works with one device but not the other, you simply haven't paired the mobile device where it doesn't work.